# Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=2 "Reading is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Reading is not permitted.}

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am developing app which manage BLE device.
I am trying to write data in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor` method like below.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let characteristics = service.characteristics {
                    for characteristic in characteristics {
                        if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: Common.PinUUID) {
            var varInt = 0
            let data = Data.init(bytes: &varInt, count: 1);
            peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
                        }
        }
    }
```

When I try to write data on characteristic then I got error like below.

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x283b213e0, UUID = 47E9EE30-47E9-11E4-8939-164230D1DF67, properties = 0x8, value = (null), notifying = NO> - Optional("Writing is not permitted.")
```

My characteristic is Write only type. I don't know why it shows error like this.

Also when I try to read data then I call like below.

```
  if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: Common.TemperatureDataUUID) {
            print(characteristic)
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
   }
```

I got error like below,

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x283e77300, UUID = 47E9EE2B-47E9-11E4-8939-164230D1DF67, properties = 0xA, value = (null), notifying = NO> - Optional("Reading is not permitted.")
```

How to solve it not finding any solution? Please help.

Comment: I was the faced same issue earlier While connecting MI band 3 with iOS Device. Fixed issue by setting authentication to Bluetooth device before access the data. I will share sample code soon

Comment: Hi I am also got an issue when I sent data one connected device to other device. func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) { I am getting Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.  Some device it is working fine and data sent but not getting any response other device as well notification .How to read same data in other device.@Vikas @ COVID19

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously the permissions that are set on the peripheral side does not allow read and write. There is probably nothing wrong with your iOS code.

Please again check the peripheral GATT db to see if it's defined correctly.

Comment: That means, I have to check device database??

Comment: Yes check the code on the peripheral since that's the device actually sending the error code.

Comment: Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=2 "Reading is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Reading is not permitted.}

Comment: The peripheral is incorrectly set up. It sets the Read property bit, but has not set Read permission. Please check the firmware of that device. There is probably nothing wrong with your iOS code.

Comment: Well in that case it must be something that happens in the communication flow that later makes the peripheral to reject the request with "read not permitted". You should really check the peripheral why it sends that error code in the first place.